# Email Regex Validation fails in python

Tags: python, regex

I am using python to extract Emails from web using `re` library. it does its job but it extracts links that match the pattern. For example:

```
/images/paramproofs/services/pgp/logo_black_16@2x.png
/images/paramproofs/services/twitter/logo_black_16@2x.png
/images/paramproofs/services/github/logo_black_16@2x.png
/images/paramproofs/services/reddit/logo_black_16@2x.png
/images/paramproofs/services/web/logo_black_16@2x.png
/images/paramproofs/services/web/logo_black_16@2x.png
/images/paramproofs/services/stellar/logo_black_16@2x.png
/images/badges/install-badge-windows-168-56@2x.png
/images/badges/install-badge-windows-168-56@3x.png
```

This is the pattern I use:

`` (?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[ a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\]) ``

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know where you took that regex from, but according to [emailregex.com](http://emailregex.com/) this should suffice for almost all cases (including yours):

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)
```

The line anchors (`^` for the beginning of the line and `$` for the end) are the key here.

Comment: While true, the answer should be: write an actual email to the possible address.